# Image ratio option changing after render, to most recent ratio selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I modified an image cropper so that it allows you to pre-select which crop ratio option you would like to use, before or after the image to crop is selected. The issue is that when I set the ratio that is selected into the URL which is submitted through the API, it is changing if the user renders an image, but before submitting the image with its ratio, the user selects a different ratio option to test, before submitting the previous render. I need a way to lock in the original ratio to the URL being submitted, without it being changed by selecting another crop option.

This is the code that renders the final image after cropping, along with the submission functionality:

```
    // As soon as the user clicks the render button...
    // Listen for "Render final image" click
    renderButton.click(function (event) {
        var dataUrl;
        $(".result, .share-link").empty();
        $(".submit, .remove").remove();

        imgly.renderToDataURL("image/jpeg", {
            size: "1200"
        }, function (err, dataUrl) {
            // `dataUrl` now contains a resized rendered image

            //Convert DataURL to Blob to send over Ajax
            function dataURItoBlob(dataUrl) {
                // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string

                var byteString = atob(dataUrl.split(',')[1]);

                // separate out the mime component
                var mimeString = dataUrl.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

                // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
                var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
                for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
                //var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                //bb.append(ab);
                //return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
                return new Blob([ab], {
                    type: 'image/jpeg'
                });
            }


            var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
            //console.log("var blob: " + blob);
            //var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
            var image = $("<img id='result'><br>").attr({
                src: dataUrl
            });


            image.appendTo($(".result"));


            $submitButton = $('<div class="btn btn-success submit"></div>')
                .text('Submit ' + imageid.value).appendTo($(".submit-well"))
                .on('click', function () {
                var imageid = $("#imageid").val();
                var saveImage = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl);
                var bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');

                //IF TESTING ON LOCALHOST
                if (document.domain == 'localhost') {
                    url = "http://localhost:7777/proxy/staging/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + imageid + "/image/orientation/" + orientation;
                } else {
                    //IF IN PRODUCTION
                    url = "/cropper/admin/cropv2/rest/v1/cms/story/id/" + imageid + "/image/orientation/" + orientation;
                };

                jQuery.ajax({
                    method: "PUT",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    callback: null,
                    url: url,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": bearerToken
                    },
                    data: saveImage,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#renderButton").css("display", "hidden");
                        var obj = response;
                        $(".search-results").empty();
                        $(".submit").remove();
                        for (var property in obj.entity.entries) {
                            if (obj.entity.entries.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                                $(".search-results").append($("<li><a href='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "' target='_blank'><div class='thumbnail'><img width='30' height='30' src='" + obj.entity.entries[property].uri + "'/></img><div class='caption'><p>" + obj.entity.entries[property].orientation + "</p></div></a></li>"));
                            }
                        }
                        $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-success'><p>The asset <b>" + imageid + "</b> now has a <b>" + orientation + "</b> image associated with it.</p></div>");
                        $("#imageid, .assetid").css("border-color", "#ccc");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $("#renderButton").hide();
                        $(".share-link").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>Image submission error. Asset ID missing or invalid. Please check asset ID, re-render and try again.</p></div>");
                        $("#imageid, .assetid").css("border-color", "red");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This is the function with dropdown selector and switch case that controls the orientation selection:

```
    CropOperation.prototype.setSize = function(size) {
  //SHOW/HIDE CROP OPTIONS BASED ON SELECTION
  $(".imgly-controls-item-square").hide(); // Hide square crop before images are even loaded
  $("#renderButton").hide();
  $('#crop').on('change', function () {
    $(".submit").hide();
  //$('.imgly-controls-list-with-buttons').show();
        if (this.value == 'now'){
          $(".imgly-controls-item-16-9").click();
          $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-landscape.png")');
            $(".imgly-controls-button-back, .imgly-controls-item-16-9, .imgly-controls-item-9-16, .imgly-controls-button-done").show();
            $(".imgly-controls-item-square").hide(); // hide square crop option after user selects livefeeds, then back to now
        } else if (this.value == 'livefeeds') {
            // SET CROP RATIO TO SQUARE
            $(".imgly-controls-item-square").click();
            //          
          $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-square.png")');
            $(".imgly-controls-item-square, .imgly-controls-button-back, .imgly-controls-button-done").show();
            $(".imgly-controls-item-16-9, .imgly-controls-item-9-16").hide();
        } else if(this.value == 'default'){
            $(".imgly-controls-item-16-9, .imgly-controls-item-9-16, .imgly-controls-item-square, .imgly-controls-button-back, .imgly-controls-button-done").hide();
        }

    });
    var h, height, w, width, _ref;
    _ref = this.app.ui.getCanvas().getImageData(), width = _ref.width, height = _ref.height;
    this.options.size = size;
    this.options.start.set(0.1, 0.1);
    this.options.end.set(0.9, 0.9);
    switch (size) {
      case "9:16":
        this.options.ratio = 9 / 16;
        orientation = "PORTRAIT";
        $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-portrait.png")');
        break;
      case "square":
        this.options.ratio = 1;
        orientation = "SQUARE";
        $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-square.png")');
        break;
      case "16:9":
        this.options.ratio = 16 / 9;
        orientation = "LANDSCAPE";
        $(".imgly-canvas-cropping-center").css('background-image', 'url("crop-landscape.png")');
        break;
    }
    if (this.options.ratio) {
      if (width / height <= this.options.ratio) {
        this.options.start.x = 0.1;
        this.options.end.x = 0.9;
        h = 1 / height * (width / this.options.ratio * 0.8);
        this.options.start.y = (1 - h) / 2;
        this.options.end.y = 1 - this.options.start.y;
      } else {
        this.options.start.y = 0.1;
        this.options.end.y = 0.9;
        w = 1 / width * (this.options.ratio * height * 0.8);
        this.options.start.x = (1 - w) / 2;
        this.options.end.x = 1 - this.options.start.x;
      }
    }
    return this.emit("updateOptions", this.options);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set `var ratio = orientation;` within the `renderButton` function, and replace the URL being submitted as `+ ratio +`, instead of `+ orientation +`. This keeps the orientation in the url from being changed every time a different orientation is clicked, regardless of whether it is being submitted as that newly clicked orientation or not.